How do I run 2 different versions of TinyMCE in the same project
I need to self-host 2 versions (4 & 6) of TinyMCE in the same react.js web app. Is it possible to do this or can you only run 1 version in a project?
Using the TinyMCE Editor react package it only seems to run the version placed in the public folder of the web app by default.
I put 2 versions of the TinyMCE source folder in the public folder of my web app project and renamed them to include the version of TinyMCE but the TinyMCE Editor component only worked if the folder was named 'tinymce', adding the version numbers to the folder stopped it from working.
